# Как установить слушатель на определенный view внутри элемента списка ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Есть кастомная разметка для элемента ListVIew. В нем три TextView. Как отловить нажатие на каждый из них?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте `onClickListener`  на каждый `textview` в адаптаре

```
public class FundAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fund> {

    private int resource;

    public FundAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Fund> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout view;

        Fund fund = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            vi.inflate(resource, view, true);
        } else {
            view = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        TextView quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        TextView itemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.walletItem);

        quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               <--А ТУТ ВСЕ ДЕЙСТВИЯ КОТОРЫЕ ХОТИТЕ СДЕЛАТЬ)-->
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             <--А ТУТ ВСЕ ДЕЙСТВИЯ КОТОРЫЕ ХОТИТЕ СДЕЛАТЬ)-->

            }
        }); 
        return view;
    }

}
```

Как видно из примера на оба `TextView` наложен слушатель

```
quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   <--А ТУТ ВСЕ ДЕЙСТВИЯ КОТОРЫЕ ХОТИТЕ СДЕЛАТЬ)-->
                }
            });
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 <--А ТУТ ВСЕ ДЕЙСТВИЯ КОТОРЫЕ ХОТИТЕ СДЕЛАТЬ)-->

                }
            });
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример

Comment: Лучше ты выложи сюда свой адаптр я его сделаю

Comment: Хочешь вложи свой код часть только где ты переопределяешь BaseAdapter я тебе покажу на воем примере

Comment: Я использую Fundapter, он импортируется..

Comment: Держи поискал вгитхабе фундамент адаптр прописал внеи 2 листенера )и также аналогично для 3х текстови для 4х)

Comment: Если мой ответ тебя устроит )то прошу принять ответ как верный)также мое решение одно из немногих ты в прве выбирать тот что тебе больше нравтся!)удачи!

Comment: Дорогой друг! Спасибо за помощь, за способность откликнуться и потраченное время! Прошу обратить внимание на мой ник. Я понимаю, что прописать onClickListener для каждого textview в адаптере это верное решение, но не совсем понял, что за класс FundAdapter и что мне с этим делать?

Comment: Я тебе это как бы изменный вд адаптера в который я кладу сви значения и уже облегчаю себе работу с ними ,посматри на ютубе видео

Comment: ListView Custom Adapter и ты все поймеш

Comment: Человек, которому кажется, будто он очень ясно излагает мысли, не всегда бывает понятен другим, потому что он идет от мыслей к словам, а слушатель — от слов к мыслям

Comment: Принимаю ответ, так как я неправильно поставил вопрос

Comment: Удачи поверь главое стараться потом все получится!